# Can't add user in ASP.NET Web Site Adminstration Tool

Tags: asp.net, configuration, visual-studio-2008-sp1, sqlmembershipprovider

I have added the SQL Role Provider and SQL Membership Provider to an existing application and set the authentication mode to Windows. I have created roles, but I cannot add users.

In the Security Tab of Web Site Administration Tool, I search for my user name and get the following:

> No users found for this search.

It is my expectation that the tool would search AD for users. Am I supposed to add users to the aspnet_Users table manually? Or is there some key configuration element I'm supposed to set in the Web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx) by Scott Gu on how to do what you want.

Comment: That's a great article! I was a bit surprised to see that I needed to handle this programmatically, but a lot of this was code I wanted to write anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Forms authentication should be used in order to add users through the WebSite Administration Tool. WHen using Windows authentication new users must be added by creating a new account in ActiveDirectory on the domain.